# How to dynamically load a javascript file avoiding cache?

Tags: javascript

I want to load js files dynamically with different names avoiding cache.
Now I am doing with PHP but I can't use it in a new project.

```
<?php echo '<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js?v='.round(microtime(true)).'"></script>';?>
```

Comment: Need more details: why can't you use this in a new project?

Comment: I need to load dynamic .js files according a selected language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works! I create the script object with HTML. Then I can dynamically assign the name and a version timestamp parameter.

```html
<script id="myScript"></script>
<script>     
  var microTime = Date.now();   
  var myVar = "myJsFile";
  var myUrl = myVar+'.js' + '?v=' + microTime;

  myScript.src = myUrl;
</script>
```